# Does taking birth control break my fast?

Tags: ramadan, birth-control

I need to take birth control to keep things safe between my boyfriend and I but Ramadan has come and I am fasting because I am a devout Muslim and I am wondering if taking the birth control breaks my fast? I need to take it everyday at 12 pm so it's during the day and I cannot skip a day.

Question: **Does taking birth control break my fast?**
*I need to take it everyday at 12 pm so it's during the day and I cannot skip a day.*

Comment: Ingesting\injecting anything intentionally during daytime breaks the fast.

Comment: I edited your question earlier and I recommend you to keep the edits in order to keep it focused on the question instead of going in to details about having a boyfriend and such. This will generate better answers.

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, yes, it breaks your fast. (I edited the question for those of you who got triggered by my answer.)

Comment: This is not a site for making judgements on others; just stick to the question please.

Comment: @Rebecca This is why I edited her question and removed the part of boyfriend and devote in order to make the question more focused on the birth control pills and avoid judgments. But it seems the edit was removed.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.